# Passing variable from other modules and put it in a format

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question as I am not familiar on how to code the format as I am passing a variable which is a number from other modules. I have posted my code `sub record` (this is a module 9 in my excel vba). This sub module is where I need to modify a field into certain format and there are values I need to pass from other module. I am passing a variable from module 2 which will return a number as I have declare it as `Public myVal As String` as I need this `Myval` value and insert it in to this Field 3 in a format.

The field 3 value is `000000000209644` (15 digits of numbers) I need to modify into something like this `020161201209644`

1. 0201612 = 0+YYYYMM
2. 01 = myval value from other module 2
3. 209644 = is the current number data in this file.

The following is my sample code to show what i am doing

```
Sub record()

Dim myfile, mysfile, myxfile As String

myfile = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\PaymentFile02.xlsx"
Open DatFile1Name For Output As #1

Application.Workbooks.Open FileName:=myfile
vRow = 2
While Cells(vRow, 1).Value <> ""
    Field1 = Cells(vRow, 1).Value
    Field2 = Cells(vRow, 2).Value
    Field3 = Cells(vRow, 3).Value ' this is the variable where i need to do formatting

    Dim Str As String
    str =""
    str = field1 & "|" & field2 & "|" & Field3 & "|"
    Print #1, str
    vRow = vRow + 1 ' this is incremental as there are a lot of rows
Wend
Close #1

ActiveWorkbook.Close
MsgBox ("File PaymentFile02.TXT created")

End Sub
```

Sample Data for field 1, field 2 and field 3:

```
00|HELLO|000000000209644|
```

Comment: see if the code in my answer below works for you as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below does the `Str` Merge like you wanted in your post.

**Note**: take into considoration, that it takes the first 6 digits to the right (out of your 15 digits) - that's a constant format in the code below (can be modifed to fit other scenarios).

```
Sub record(myVal As String)

Dim myfile As String, mysfile As String, myxfile As String

myfile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PaymentFile02.xlsx"

Open DatFile1Name For Output As #1
Application.Workbooks.Open (myfile)

vRow = 2
While Cells(vRow, 1).Value <> ""
    field1 = Cells(vRow, 1).Value
    field2 = Cells(vRow, 2).Value

    ' this assumes your value in Column C will allways take 6 digits from the right
    Field3 = 0 & Format(Date, "YYYYMM") & myVal & Format(Cells(vRow, 3).Value, "000000") ' This is the variable where i need to do formatting

    Dim Str As String

    Str = ""
    Str = field1 & "|" & field2 & "|" & Field3 & "|"

    Debug.Print Str

    Print #1, Str
    vRow = vRow + 1 ' This is incremental as there are a lot of rows
Wend
Close #1

ActiveWorkbook.Close
MsgBox ("File PaymentFile02.TXT created")

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what i need, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Build your str using Format.

Format Function (Visual Basic for Applications)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx

Str = "0" & format (field1,"YYYYMM") & etc.

Dunno if your 3 field3's should be field1, field2 and field3...

Comment: hi, i've added the sample data for my field 1, field 2 and field 3

Comment: yeah, it should be field 1, field 2 and field 3, sorry for the mistakes

Comment: But how am i going to pass my variables from other modules, the Myval from other modules

Comment: Try field3 = "0" & format (now (),"YYYYMM") & format (myVal,"00") & format (cint (field3), "000000")

Comment: Sorry, not near computer to check my syntax but you should get the idea.

Comment: Bring myVal in as a parameter of sub record. <code>Sub record (myVal as string) </code> and pass it from the other sub.  Sub record defaults to public so should be visible from other modules.